# Perl Sublime Text format off when using Regex in source

Tags: perl

I am pretty new at both Perl and Sublime. I have a line of code using Regex Find and Replace and everything below it is now Yellow as if it's a quoted string.

How should this line be written so that it both works and doesn't mess up the rest of my code visually?

The file runs without error.

```
if($file =~ /$pattern/ ) {
        my $originalname = $file =~ s/$pattern//r;
```

I've tried putting tick and quotes around the actual pattern which fixes the sublime formatting but breaks the code.

I think its a Sublime problem as TextMate doesn't exhibit the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a comment with an additional slash there.

```
if($file =~ /$pattern/ ) { # /
        my $originalname = $file =~ s/$pattern//r; # /
```

Not every syntax highlighter is perfect. The one Stack Overflow uses also does not get this right, as you can see above.

Comment: @J.P. If this solved your problem please accept the answer by ticking the check mark ✅. Thank you. Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: @J.P.  Also note that _sometimes_ you have to try other characters in that comment, as `/` doesn't help.  It depends on why the pattern breaks the highlighter, and it's usually about a non-letter character that appears (perhaps repeatedly) in the pattern. The `#/` does help most of the time. (If it doesn't I just try others, like `#'` or `#{` ...)